# Given a generator for a cyclic subgroup of size d, is there a method to find any other of the $\varphi(d)-1$ generators for that subgroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, cyclic-groups

I'm given a generator for a subgroup, can I find any other generators?

Comment: You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow [a few guidelines](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).  In particular, what have you tried so far, and just where are you stuck? This is not a homework-answering site: we want to see that you have put significant work into the problem.

Answer (score 2):

> If $G$ is cyclic and finite with generator $g$ then $g^a$ is a generator for all $a$ coprime to $\lvert G \rvert$,

because if $\gcd(a,\lvert G\rvert) = 1$ then there exist $m,n \in \mathbb{Z}$ with $ma + n\lvert G\rvert = 1$, so
$$ (g^a)^m = g^{1-n\lvert G\rvert} = g.$$